# Arch linux - Wacom display on thinkpad does not read any input

Tags: arch-linux, x11, x-server, xinput, wacom

I have an issue with my wacom display on my thinkpad x390. The linux does not react to any movement of stylus or buttons on pen. I have wacom drivers installed.

this is output of `libwacom-list-local-devices`:

```
devices:
- name: 'Wacom ISDv4 51af'
  bus: 'usb'
  vid: '0x056a'
  pid: '0x51af'
  nodes:
  - /dev/input/event9
  - /dev/input/event7
```

This is output of `xinput`:

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser    id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output of `xinput list-props 9`:

```
Device 'Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger':
    Device Enabled (186):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (188): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix (315):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix Default (316):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (298): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (299):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (300):    0, 0
    Device Node (301):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (302):    1386, 20911
```

output of `xinput list-props 17`

```
Device 'Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser':
    Device Enabled (186):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (188): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (309): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (310):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (311):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (312):    10.000000
    Device Node (301):  "/dev/input/event9"
    Wacom Tablet Area (324):    0, 0, 29376, 16524
    Wacom Rotation (325):   0
    Wacom Pressurecurve (326):  0, 0, 100, 100
    Wacom Serial IDs (327): 20911, 0, 10, 0, 0
    Wacom Serial ID binding (328):  0
    Wacom Proximity Threshold (329):    10
    Wacom Pressure Threshold (330): 26
    Wacom Sample and Suppress (331):    2, 4
    Wacom Enable Touch (332):   0
    Wacom Enable Touch Gesture (334):   0
    Wacom Touch Gesture Parameters (335):   0, 0, 250
    Wacom Tool Type (336):  "ERASER" (403)
    Wacom button action 0 (337):    1572865
    Wacom button action 1 (338):    1572866
    Wacom button action 2 (339):    1572867
    Wacom button action 3 (340):    1572872
    Wacom Button Actions (341): "Wacom button action 0" (337), "Wacom button action 1" (338), "Wacom button action 2" (339), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0), "Wacom button action 3" (340)
    Wacom Pressure Recalibration (342): 1
    Wacom Panscroll Threshold (343):    1300
    Device Product ID (302):    1386, 20911
    Wacom Debug Levels (344):   0, 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have the device in front of me, here are some ways that I personally would go about debugging it.

If you try running `xev` in a terminal and then (while the white window is focused) look at the terminal output, does any event fire when

- You press any buttons on the tablet/stylus?
- When you hover the stylus over the tablet/screen?
- When you press down the stylus to the tablet/screen?

This will help you determine what the culprit of the problem is.

Some other questions that can help include:

- Does it work inside of a drawing program like krita or inkscape?
- What kind of window manager and/or desktop manager are you using?

Perhaps this might draw you closer to a conclusion on the issue, without more information, this is as vaguely as I can answer for now.

Comment: xev does not recognize any events. It does not work in any program. I use i3wm.